# Dynamic output table pentaho

Tags: variables, dynamic, output, pentaho

In the ETL pentaho I would like to output my data in a dynamic "table output".

I am using the variable `pil016_ext_wxxx` which I entered in "table output" --> "target table"

I obtain an error as if he did not detect the data I input. (While it works if I just execute an SQL statement in the transformation with this variable)

> 2018/10/29 17:56:25 - pil016.pil016_ext_wxxx_temp 2.0 - The tablename
>   is not defined (empty)

[image: An image of my parameters inside table output]

Do you know if it is possible to output data in a dynamic table in pentaho ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for the `Metadata Injection` step, [documented here](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection).

Your case is covered by [Diethard's tutorial](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com/2011/07/metadata-driven-etl-and-reporting.html)  (jump to the **Metadata driven ETL** section).